# Что делать, если твой код кажется говнокодом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, pyqt

Что делать, если я пишу код, что-то делаю, но мне постоянно кажется, что мой код - полный отстой и говнокодище?

Я из-за этого работать нормально не могу и каждую минуту переписываю свой код, гоняя из пустого в порожнее.

Помогите :(

Вот мой код:

модуль **gui.py** - основной модуль, в котором я рисую интерфейс:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
                             QLabel, QBoxLayout, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QGridLayout, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPalette, QColor, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QSize, Qt, QObject
from logic import *

import rage_gui as rgui
import sys

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, title, posX=0, posY=0, sizeW=100, sizeH=100, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.posX, self.posY = posX, posY
        self.sizeW, self.sizeH = sizeW, sizeH

        self.setGeometry(posX, posY, sizeW, sizeH)
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        back = rgui.RCVBackground(self)
        
        back.setTitleLabel("Выберите настройки:")
        back.appendWidget(rgui.RCSameLine((
            QLabel("Распознавание:"),
            QPushButton("Включить")
            )))
        
        back.setVStretch(True)

if __name__=="__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    deskX, deskY = QApplication.desktop().width(), QApplication.desktop().height()
    width, height = 600, 500

    window = App("Fuck...", deskX//2-width//2, deskY//2-height//2, width, height)
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Модель **rage_gui.py** - модуль, в который я выношу полезные классы, чтобы сократить код и уменьшить рутинную работу:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class RCSameLine(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, widgets=[]):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        for widget in widgets:
            layout.addWidget(widget)

        layout.addStretch(1)

class RCVBackground(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.widgets = []
        self.back = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.back)
        parent.setCentralWidget(self)

    def appendWidget(self, widget):
        self.back.addWidget(widget)

    def setTitleLabel(self, text):
        title = QLabel(text)
        title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.back.addWidget(title)

    def setVStretch(self, stretch=False):
        if stretch: self.back.addStretch(1)
```

---

Это обрезок кода, минимальный. И вот мне кажется, что я постоянно делаю что-то не так. Что можно сделать проще или то, что я вообще пишу какую-то дичь. Может самовнушение, а может...

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]  и лучше расскажите, что вас в нем смущает.

Comment: [Extract Method](https://refactoring.guru/ru/extract-method), [Inline Method](https://refactoring.guru/ru/inline-method), повторить

Comment: Отредактировал, добавил кусок кода для примера

Comment: Конкретно: меня смущает в нем классы, которые я добавил. Стоят ли они вообще того. И насколько код чистый вообще? Мне постоянно кажется, что я пишу полный бред. А может и не кажется...

Comment: Ну... не знаю. Обилие классов по моему норм, хотя я могу так думать из за того что я программирую на Jave где в принципе классы это то на чем держится вся программа

Comment: Пацталом с вопроса )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое мнение очень субъективное.
Я бы не стал делать класс `RCVBackground` - это центральное окно
и я вижу действия, которые вы в нем прописали, должны быть в `main.py`.

Класс `RCSameLine` очень даже имеет смысл, т.к. наделен определенной функциональностью.

Я не знаю какой конечный вид должно получить ваше главное окно,
поэтому менеджеры компоновки не менял.
Я добавил `setStyleSheet`, чтобы вы видели где реально располагается
и как отрисовывается объект, созданный классом `RCSameLine`.
Я добавил виджет `QGroupBox`, потому что без него мне не понравилось.

Мне так кажется, что без `QScrollArea` вам не обойтись https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel, QBoxLayout, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QGridLayout, QSizePolicy,
    QGroupBox
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPalette, QColor, QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QSize, Qt, QObject

# ? from logic import *

#from rage_gui import RCSameLine
# вы можете перенести этот класс в отдельный модуль, разницы никакой нет.
class RCSameLine(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, widgets=[], parent=None):
        super(RCSameLine, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(200, 70)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #bbb; ")
        self.group_box_settings = QGroupBox(f'{widgets[0].text()}', self)   

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self.group_box_settings)  
        for widget in widgets:
            layout.addWidget(widget)
# ?       layout.addStretch(1)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, title, posX=0, posY=0, sizeW=100, sizeH=100, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.posX, self.posY = posX, posY
        self.sizeW, self.sizeH = sizeW, sizeH
        self.setGeometry(posX, posY, sizeW, sizeH)
        self.setWindowTitle(title)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)  
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)        
# ?        self.widgets = []
        
        titleLabel = self.setTitleLabel("Выберите настройки:")
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(titleLabel) 

        self.rguiLabel = QLabel("Распознавание:")
        self.rguiButton = QPushButton("Включить")
        self.rcSameLine = RCSameLine([self.rguiLabel, self.rguiButton], self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.rcSameLine)
        self.rguiLabel2 = QLabel("Распознавание_2:")
        self.rguiButton2 = QPushButton("Включить_2")        
        self.rcSameLine2 = RCSameLine([self.rguiLabel2, self.rguiButton2], self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.rcSameLine2)

        self.setVStretch(True)   # тоже не совсем понятно, 
                                 # почему не просто 'self.mainLayout.addStretch(1)'

#?    def appendWidget(self, widget):
#?        self.back.addWidget(widget)

    def setTitleLabel(self, text):
        self.titleLabel = QLabel(f"<h1>{text}</h1>")
        self.titleLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        return self.titleLabel

    def setVStretch(self, stretch=False):
        if stretch: self.mainLayout.addStretch(1)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    deskX, deskY = QApplication.desktop().width(), QApplication.desktop().height()
    width, height = 600, 500
    window = MainWindow("Fuck...", deskX//2-width//2, deskY//2-height//2, width, height)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто мне не нравится нагромождения кода, которые получаются при написании гуи на PyQt5. Я хотел сделать так, чтобы можно было написать одну строку и уже был сразу Виджет (в данном случае это RCVBackground) на котором можно было бы легко размещать виджеты при помощи RCSameLine. Но получилась какая-то хрень. В моем коде мне не нравится то, что нельзя "красивым" способом получить доступ к виджетам в sameLine, да и RCVBackground оказался бесполезным

Comment: Кстати я посмотрел ваш код и у меня появился вопрос: В чем разница между widget.setLayout(layout) и созданием слоя с указанием родителя layout = QHBoxLayout(parent)?

Comment: @CSharpLooser разницы никакой нет.